# What do you call a person who checks if everything is all right?

Tags: word-request

Talking about roles for people, what do you call a person who is in charge of **checking** or verifying that every part of a procedure is working okay?

I was thinking "reviewer" but it does not sound quite correct to me.

Comment: **auditor**? **inspector**?

Comment: organizer maybe?

Comment: The terminology may vary from what they are checking. Is there a context for this? Perhaps you're looking for a person who checks something in specific?

Comment: I would use "auditor".

Comment: @VarunNair Say there is a "operator" who is performing a procedure (for example feeding tablets to a machine) and there is another person who verifies if that procedure is done correctly

Comment: What kind of procedure? Quality control is the correct word in many contexts. But you haven't given enough details to make a good answer. Supervisor is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of the word [***supervisor***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/supervisor)? I think that's exactly what you're looking for: *a supervisor is a person who supervises activities or people, especially workers or students.*

Answer (score 0):

*Corrector*, an old name for *proofreader*.

*Script girl*, now called *continuity supervisor*.

*Consultant* would fit the bill in many contexts.

In space flight they are called *flight controllers*.